# How to display category and their sub-category

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have table like this

```
cat:
----
cat_id    name
---------------
1        cat-1
2        cat-2 


sub-cat:
--------

id    cat_id    name
-------------------------
1       1       sub-cat-1
2       1       sub-cat-2
3       2       sub-cat-3
4       2       sub-cat-4
```

I need output like using PHP

```
cat-1
 sub-cat-1
 sub-cat-2
cat-2
 sub-cat-3
 sub-cat-4
```

and my query is

```
SELECT * FROM `cat` 
        JOIN `sub-cat`  ON cat.cat_id = sub-cat.cat_id
```

Comment: do you need the queries in code-igniter?

Comment: i fetched the result using the above query, i need to display using PHP

Comment: Just a suggestion, have you considered using a different database structure? Personally I think having `id | parentCat | name` would be a much better idea. That way you can also have more levels of sub-categories.

Comment: @Supericy-nice approach for my requirement, but the thing is DB design and all has done by higher people we don't have access to modify. Anyway i will suggest this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up with this code in `smarty`

```
{assign var=foo value=''}

{foreach from=$blog_lists key=k item=blog }
          {if $foo neq $blog ->category_id}
              {$blog->category_name}<br />
              {assign var=foo value=$blog->category_id}
          {/if}

          {$blog->subcat_name}<br />

{/foreach}
```

Comment: Seems OK, however, why you are using two different table? Why not just one? The second table structure can fullfill your need for both cat and sub-cat.

Comment: @Rana- DB design and all already done by seniors, no access to edit the table structure. anyway I'll suggest this approach...

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `cat` ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
   echo "cat ".$row['name'];
   $sql1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `sub-cat` where id = ".$row['cat_id']);
   while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1))
   {
        echo "sub-cat ".$row1['name'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
function tree($pid='',$new_ar=array())
{
if($pid!="")
{
    $new_ar1=array();
    $sel="select name from subcat where cat_id=".$pid." order by cat_id";
    $mq=mysql_query($sel);
    while($fe=mysql_fetch_assoc($mq))
    {
        array_push($new_ar1,$fe["name"]);
    }
    return $new_ar1;
}
else
{
    $sel="select name from cat order by name";
    $mq=mysql_query($sel);
    while($fe=mysql_fetch_assoc($mq))
    {
        array_push($new_ar,$fe["name"]);

        $new_ar[$fe["name"]]=array();

        array_push($new_ar[$fe["name"]],tree($fe["name"],$new_ar));

    }
}
//die($sel);
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($new_ar);
//echo "<pre>";
    return $new_ar;
}
```

call the function

```
tree();
```

Comment: it will return an array. process that array.